# How to load and predict a pre-trained tensorflow model into Java code?

Tags: java, python, tensorflow, deeplearning4j

I am not sure what’s the common practice to load a pre-trained keras model into a Java code?

I saw [deeplearning4j](https://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/keras-import-model-import) and [Google's native Java support](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_java).

Surprisingly, google says:

> Caution: The TensorFlow Java API is not covered by the TensorFlow API stability guarantees.

I am really confused, what's going on here and what are consideration I need to take before choosing a tensorflow Java engine. Obviously I would like to support the latest CUDA/ cuDNN. My application runs on PCs it's not a mobile application.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps :

1. You can use TensorFlow Lite or TensorFlow Mobile. TensorFlow Lite is recommended. Visit [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite).
2. TensorFlow Lite has a gradle as well as maven dependency which is useful in Android and java.
3. To convert your python model to TF Lite file use functions in this [notebook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IUIn9ffk5ICKujqPyuGaHL2irQ9Wmtpm/view?usp=drivesdk)
4. It can run inferences on the model which you trained in python. But, TF Lite has issues with LSTM cells and BatchNormalization layers.

Comment: My application works on HPC. Can you add some note about that as well?

Comment: @0x90: please check this, as it talks about Tensorflow on HPC: http://randomlydistributed.blogspot.com/2016/05/tensorflow-on-hpc-blue-waters.html . maybe this would help?

Comment: @a3.14_Infinity, thanks. Is it still based practice? the post is from 2016. What if I want it to run also on a regular PC with strong GPU?